# List not filled with new data by AsyncValue after ScrollController execute its listener

Tags: flutter, riverpod

how to fill the *List* with data by fetching from API page 2. When build, the *List* is filled with data from page 1, but after the *ListView* is scrolled to the end doesn't fill the *List*, even *load* is changed to *true* and *map* is also been updated, it only showing loading text at the end of *ListView*. When I try to insert string manually with a button, it works flawlessly, but when I change to inserting using an *AsyncValue.whenData* doesn't work. I've tried using *ValueListenableBuilder* of *load* as *ValueNotifier* to check inside *build()* and wrapping *_list.insert* with *setState()* still not working.
Please help, thank you.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DataList(),
    );
  }
}

class DataList extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const DataList({super.key});
  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _DataListState();
}

class _DataListState extends ConsumerState<DataList> {
  AsyncValue<APIData>? asyncString;
  List<String> _list = [];
  Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
  int page = 0;
  bool load = false;
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  fillTHElist(List<String> theString) {
    for (var i = 0; i < theString.length; i++) {
      _list.insert(theString.length, theString[i]);
    }
  }

  scrollLoad() {
    if (scrollController.position.pixels ==
        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      setState(() {
        page++;
        map.update('page', (value) => page);
        load = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    page = 1;
    map.addAll({'page': page});
    scrollController.addListener(scrollLoad);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    scrollController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    asyncString = ref.watch(providerAPIString(APIFiltering(map: map)));
    if (load) {
      asyncString!.whenData((value) => fillTHElist(value.list_string));
    }

    return ListView.builder(
      controller: scrollController,
      itemCount: _list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (_list.isEmpty) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else if (index == _list.length) {
          return Text('loading ...');
        } else {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(_list[index]),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

final providerAPIString =
    StreamProvider.autoDispose.family<String, APIFiltering>((ref, map) async* {
  final data = await ref.watch(providerAPI).getData(map.map);
  yield data!.data;
});

class APIFiltering extends Equatable {
  final Map<String, dynamic> map;

  APIFiltering({required this.map});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [map];
}
```

## edit

#### added from *comment*, in case if anyone here are confused by my question.

My objective is everytime `ScrollController` has reaching its end, the `page` increase by 1 and the `asyncString` is fetching new `APIData` based on `page`'s changes, then insert `APIData.list_string` to the `_list` so that `_list`'s length will increase as well, its *growable* by default (isn't it?) And then `ListView.builder()` showing all `_list`'s element. My code only works on page 1, I've check if its get the new data, and its there, I can `print()` the `APIData` but can't add/insert it into `_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time `build(...)` is called you reset `page` to 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's just an example, actually `page` is iniated at `init()`

Comment: Is `map` supposed to be a list of pages to fetch, or just the current page (why not an int)?  Because I don't think a map can have multiple entries with the same key (`'page'`).

Comment: The `Asyncvalue<APIData>`'s `toJson()` is like `{ "page": 1, "texts": [ "string A", "string B" ] }` and so on. `map` is purposedly for querying when fetching from API, I will change the code example

Comment: my objective is everytime `ScrollController` has reaching its end, the `page` increase by 1 and the `asyncString` is fetching new APIData based on `page`'s changes, then insert `APIData.list_string` to the `_list` so that `_list`'s length will increase as well, its growable by default (isn't it?)
And then `ListView.builder()` showing all `_list`'s element. My code only works on page 1, I've check if its get the new data, and its there, I can `print()` the `APIData` but can't add/insert it into `_list`